# How to push iterated elements into array by comma separation after each element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code as below. Where I am trying iterate domains and get it comma separated.
Even if I am assigning directly arr = selectedOption.EmailDomainlist then also it's not comma separated after each domain.
I am trying to display those domains in UI like

```
<div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions} ? {this.state.domainOptions} : 'N/A' </div>
```

```
selectedOption = {
EmailDomainlist : ["gmail.com", "yopmail.com"]
}
```

```
this.state = {domainOptions : []}
domainList = (selectedOption) => {
    let arr = [];
    selectedOption &&
      selectedOption.EmailDomainlist.map((domain) => {
        arr.push(domain);
      });
    this.setState(() => ({ domainOptions: arr }));
  };
```

output : gmail.comyopmail.com
Expected output should be like comma separated after each domains: gmail.com,yopmail.com

How can we achieve this?

how can we add ternary operator in div tag?
`<div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions} ? {this.state.domainOptions.join(', ')} : 'N/A' </div>`

the above code is displayed in UI as
Allowed domains: ( ? : N/A)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use join instead of iterating over the items:

```
<div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions ? this.state.domainOptions.join(', ') : 'N/A' } </div>
```

Comment: how can we add ternary operator in <div> tag?     <div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions} ? {this.state.domainOptions.join(', ')} : 'N/A' </div>

Comment: put them all into curly braces

Comment: it did not work I am getting error <div> Allowed domains: {{this.state.domainOptions} ? {this.state.domainOptions.join(', ')} : 'N/A' }</div>

Comment: Not like that but like this : `<div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions ? this.state.domainOptions.join(', ') : 'N/A' } </div>`

Comment: can we add error message in place of 'N/A' when we don't have domains?  `<div> Allowed domains: {this.state.domainOptions ? this.state.domainOptions.join(', ') : <span className="error">Email Domains not mapped.</span>} </div> ` when I tried like adding error in span it's not showing the error.

Comment: Use your ternary condition like this then: `{ this.state.domainOptions ? <div>Allowed domains : {this.state.domainOptions.join(', ')}</div> : <div>Error message</div>}`

Answer (score 2):

Join will do this for you.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

You probably don't need to store it in state either. In general, I wouldn't store anything in state that can be derived otherwise.

```js
const selectedOption = {
EmailDomainlist : ["gmail.com", "yopmail.com"]
};

console.log(selectedOption.EmailDomainlist.join(","));
```